# Perl regex to match first 8 digits

Tags: perl

The output shows all the digits, but I need only first 8 digits.  Can anyone please tell me how to get them?

What I've tried:

```
[root@localhost ~]# perl -e 'open (DATA, "test.txt");while (<DATA>){s/[^\d]+//g;print $_,$/;}'
20140410223029
20140411043251
20140409150003
20120801114354
```

Comment: Please don’t login as the superuser! :(

Comment: Have you tried something that failed? If so, what was the problem. You'll generally find that people on SO are more than happy to help, but they like to be shown that posters have expended some effort themselves. They are also generally pretty forgiving, so just edit your question to show what you've tried, and why you consider it inadequate and I'm sure you'll be able to sit back and bask in floods of useful answers.

Comment: what if there are fewer than 8?  do you want the first 8 digits all in a group or the first 8 even mixed in with non-digits?

Answer (score 3):

Printing only first 8 digits,

```
perl -lne 'print /^(\d{8})/' test.txt
```

or if you want to skip the lines which regex doesn't match,

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /^(\d{8})/' test.txt
```

Comment: The spec isn’t very tight, but that isn’t very robust in the face of failure to match.  Try `print $1 if /^ ( \d{8} ) /x` perhaps.

Comment: @tchrist of course, on the other hand OP might expect that all lines  should match, and empty lines would give some sort of hint.

Comment: Yeah.  The specification is not robust enough to know what should be done.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a call to `substr`

```
perl -lne 'print substr $_, 0, 8' test.txt
```

or perhaps

```
perl -lpe 'substr($_, 8) = ""' test.txt
```

Comment: @mpapec: `ysth` is being humourous and pointing out the possibility of awkward solutions using either `vec` or `unpack`!

Comment: @mpapec: `unpack` isn't too bad: `perl -lne'print unpack "A8"' test.txt` but the best I can do with `vec` is `perl -lne'print pack "N2", vec($_,0,32), vec($_,1,32)' test.txt`

Comment: @mpapec: it's been deleted, so no longer relevant